# Find duplicates in a list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm

> You are given information about users of your website. The information
>   includes username, a phone number and/or an email. Write a program
>   that takes in a list of tuples where each tuple represents information
>   for a particular user and returns a list of lists where each sublist
>   contains the indices of tuples containing information about the same
>   person. For example:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> [("MLGuy42", "andrew@gmail.com", "123-4567"),
> ("CS229DungeonMaster", "123-4567", "ml@stanford.edu"),
> ("Doomguy", "john@oculus.com", "carmack@gmail.com"),
> ("andrew26", "andrew@gmail.com", "mlguy@gmail.com")]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [[0, 1, 3], [2]]
> ```
>
> Since "MLGuy42", "CS229DungeonMaster" and "andrew26" are all the same
>   person.
>
> Each sublist in the output should be sorted and the outer list should
>   be sorted by the first element in the sublist.

Below is the code snippet that I did for this problem. It seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better/optimized solution.

```
def find_duplicates(user_info):
    results = list()
    seen = dict()
    for i, user in enumerate(user_info):
        first_seen = True
        key_info = None
        for info in user:
            if info in seen:
                first_seen = False
                key_info = info
                break
        if first_seen:
            results.append([i])
            pos = len(results) - 1
        else:
            index = seen[key_info]
            results[index].append(i)
            pos = index
        for info in user:
            seen[info] = pos
    return results
```

Comment: By the way, this is a thinly disguised [tag:union-find] problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to increase readability.  A `for-else` statement can be used to replace flags that are only set on `break`.  [Click here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) to learn more.  The `else` clause is only called if the loop completes without `break` being called.

```
def find_duplicates(user_info):
    results = list()
    seen = dict()
    for i, user in enumerate(user_info):
        for info in user:
            if info in seen:
                index = seen[info]
                results[index].append(i)
                pos = index
                break
        else:
            results.append([i])
            pos = len(results) - 1
        for info in user:
            seen[info] = pos
    return results
```

## How I tested speeds

Your code, as it currently stands, will work exactly the same with integers. So, I just randomly generated large data sets this way (and played along with `MAXVALUE` and `range` a bit.

```
from random import randrange
from timeit import timeit
MAXVALUE = 1000

for a in range(5): #I wanted to make sure I checked 5 to make sure I don't get a outlier data set that effects my ability to use timeit reasonably.
    user_info = [[randrange(MAXVALUE) for i in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)]
    print(timeit(lambda: find_duplicates(user_info), number=10000))
```

Credit for improving code: Maarten Fabré

Comment: I think your second `if info in seen:` should be `if info not in seen:`

Comment: @MaartenFabré  You're right. When I looked at it I found that it wasn't faster checking that, so I removed it all together.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A good day starts with a test

```
import unittest
#import or paste your function here

a = ('a', 'a@a', '1')
b = ('b', 'b@b', '2')
c = ('c', 'c@c', '3')
ab = ('a', 'b@b', '12')

tests = [
    ([a, b], [[0], [1]]),
    ([a, b, c], [[0], [1], [2]]),
    ([a, b], [[0], [1]]),
    ([a, ab, b], [[0, 1, 2]]),
    ([a, ab, b, c], [[0, 1, 2],[3]]),
    ([a, ab, c, b], [[0, 1, 3],[2]]),
    ([c, a, ab, b], [[0],[1, 2, 3]]),
    ([a, b, ab], [[0, 1, 2]]),
    ]

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_some(self):
        for n, t in enumerate(tests):
            ud = t[0]
            ref = t[1]
            res = find_duplicates(ud)
            assert ref==res, "n:{}, ud:{}, ref:{}, res:{}".format(n, ud, ref, res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

gives

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_some (user_info.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Verena\workspace\user_info\src\user_info.py", line xx, in test_some
    assert ref==res, "n:{}, ud:{}, ref:{}, res:{}".format(n, ud, ref, res)
AssertionError: n:7, ud:[('a', 'a@a', '1'), ('b', 'b@b', '2'), ('a', 'b@b', '12')], ref:[[0, 1, 2]], res:[[0, 2], [1]]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

Answer (score 1):

I was toying with this thinking a `defaultdict` would also work for this instead of a list of lists

I had a solution I found rather elegant with getting an intersection of `seen.keys()` and `set(user)`, but that was prohibitively slow. This solution is about as fast as [nfn neil](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/180834/123200)'s

```
def find_duplicates_defaultdict(user_info):
    results = collections.defaultdict(list)
    seen = dict()
    for i, user in enumerate(user_info):
        for info in user:
            try:
                pos = seen[info]
                break
            except KeyError:
                pass
        else:
            pos = len(results)
        results[pos].append(i)
        for info in user:
            if info not in seen:
                seen[info] = pos

    return results.values() # expects ordered defaultdict older versions of python might need something like
    return [results[key] for key in sorted(results.keys())]
```

## Order of iteration

These results depend on the order of iteration. For a list like this

```
info = [
    ("MLGuy42", "andrew@gmail.com", "123-4567"),
    ("CS229DungeonMaster", "123-4567", "ml@stanford.edu"),
    ("Doomguy", "john@oculus.com", "carmack@gmail.com"),
    ("andrew26", "another_andrew@gmail.com", "mlguy@gmail.com"),
    ("andrew26", "andrew@gmail.com", "yet_another_andrew@gmail.com")
       ]
```

it returns `[[0, 1], [2], [3, 4]]` instead of `[[0, 1, 3, 4], [2]]`, which would have been the result if line 4 was before line 3

To solve this, I found a different implementation. This requires a double iteration over the results, so it is slower, but more complete

```
def find_duplicates_set(user_info):
    subsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    subsets[0] = set(user_info[0])

    for user in user_info:
        indices = {i for i, subset in subsets.items() if not subset.isdisjoint(user)}
        if not indices:
            subsets[max(subsets.keys()) + 1] = set(user)
        elif len(indices) == 1:
            subsets[indices.pop()].update(user)
        else:
            indices = sorted(indices)
            i0 = indices.pop(0)
            subsets[i0].update(user)
            for i in indices:
                subset = subsets.pop(i)
                subsets[i0].update(subset)
    results = collections.defaultdict(list)        
    for i, user in enumerate(user_info):
        for index, subset in subsets.items():
            if not subset.isdisjoint(user):
                results[index].append(i)
                break
    return results.values()
```

## Execution speed

```
MAXVALUE = 1000
for a in range(3):
    user_info = [[randrange(MAXVALUE) for i in range(3)] for _ in range(10 * MAXVALUE)]
    print('original: ', timeit(lambda: find_duplicates(user_info), number=1000))
    print('nfn_neil: ', timeit(lambda: find_duplicates_nfn(user_info), number=1000))
    print('defaultdict: ', timeit(lambda: find_duplicates_defaultdict(user_info), number=1000))
    print('set: ', timeit(lambda: find_duplicates_set(user_info), number=1000))
```

> ```
> original:  6.129232463274093
> nfn_neil:  4.994730664504459
> defaultdict:  4.738290764427802
> set:  18.66864765893115
> original:  5.425038123095874
> nfn_neil:  4.78540134785726
> defaultdict:  4.616922919762146
> set:  19.058994075487135
> original:  5.55867017791752
> nfn_neil:  4.920460685316357
> defaultdict:  4.8429226022271905
> set:  19.008669542017742
> ```